# Definition of int64_t

Tags: c++, c, integer, long-integer

I am new to C/C++, so I have a couple of questions about a basic type:

a) Can you explain to me the difference between `int64_t` and `long` (`long int`)? 
In my understanding, both are 64 bit integers. Is there any reason to choose one over the other?

b) I tried to look up the definition of `int64_t` on the web, without much success. Is there an authoritative source I need to consult for such questions?

c) For code using `int64_t` to compile, I am currently including `<iostream>`, which doesn't make much sense to me. Are there other includes that provide a declaration of `int64_t`?

Comment: On my compiler, `sizeof(long) == 4`

Comment: there are many places where longs are not 64bit... and have you tried looking up some documentation about in64_t like the one on cppreference.com?

Comment: @DavidHefernan: That could still be 64bits ;)

Comment: All you can say about a `long` is that it is not *shorter* than an `int`.

Comment: Cdarke, not only that, you can also say that it's at least 32 bits

Comment: @sasha.sochka Well, to be more precise, it says that its range is `[−2147483647,+2147483647]`. Impossible to squeeze under 32-bits, but...

Answer (score 117, accepted):

> a) Can you explain to me the difference between `int64_t` and `long` (`long int`)? In my understanding, both are 64 bit integers. Is there any reason to choose one over the other?

The former is a signed integer type with *exactly* 64 bits. The latter is a signed integer type with *at least* 32 bits.

> b) I tried to look up the definition of `int64_t` on the web, without much success. Is there an authoritative source I need to consult for such questions?

http://cppreference.com covers this here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer. The authoritative source, however, is the [C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) (this particular bit can be found in §18.4 Integer types [cstdint]).

> c) For code using `int64_t` to compile, I am including `<iostream>`, which doesn't make much sense to me. Are there other includes that provide a declaration of `int64_t`?

It is declared in `<cstdint>` or `<cinttypes>` (under namespace `std`), or in `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>` (in the global namespace).

Comment: And for connoisseurs of the standard: `int64_t` is guaranteed to use 2's complement representation and have no padding bits, and is optional (although it's required to exist if the implementation has a standard type that fits the bill). `long int` guarantees neither and is always required to exist. And when the C++11 standard refers to "the C standard" in 18.4, it means C99.

Comment: @SteveJessop Why would someone use `int64_t` over `long int` and vice versa?

Comment: @Dave: between those two, the difference that *most commonly* influences the decision is that `long int` might only be 32 bits. So if you want to store numbers bigger than 2 billion, and you have to choose between those two, then obviously choose `int64_t`. For the vice-versa part it's trickier, because `long int` doesn't have very many compelling guaranteed properties which `int64_t` lacks. It is guaranteed to exist, though, which `int64_t` is not. And when you're writing non-portably and know the sizes, if `long int` is the size you want then just use it and get on with your life.

Answer (score 13):

`int64_t` is guaranteed by the C99 standard to be *exactly* 64 bits wide on platforms that implement it, there's no such guarantee for a `long` which is at least 32 bits so it could be more.

> §7.18.1.3 Exact-width integer types 1 The typedef name intN_t
>   designates a signed integer type with width N , no padding  bits, and
>   a two’s complement representation. Thus, int8_t denotes a signed
>   integer   type with a width of exactly 8 bits.

Answer (score 7):

`int64_t` is `typedef` you can find that in `<stdint.h>` in C

Answer (score 7):

My 2 cents,
from a current implementation Point of View and for SWIG users on k8 (x86_64) architecture.

## Linux

First `long long` and `long int` are different types
but `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(long int) == sizeof(int64_t)`

### Gcc

First try to find where and how the compiler define int64_t and uint64_t

```bash
grepc -rn "typedef.*INT64_TYPE" /lib/gcc
/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stdint-gcc.h:43:typedef __INT64_TYPE__ int64_t;
/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stdint-gcc.h:55:typedef __UINT64_TYPE__ uint64_t;
```

So we need to find this compiler macro definition

```bash
gcc -dM -E -x c /dev/null | grep __INT64                 
#define __INT64_C(c) c ## L
#define __INT64_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long int

gcc -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | grep __UINT64
#define __UINT64_C(c) c ## UL
#define __UINT64_MAX__ 0xffffffffffffffffUL
#define __UINT64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
```

### Clang

```bash
clang -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | grep INT64_TYPE
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long int
#define __UINT64_TYPE__ long unsigned int
```

Clang, GNU compilers:
`-dM` dumps a list of macros.
`-E` prints results to stdout instead of a file.
`-x c` and `-x c++` select the programming language when using a file without a filename extension, such as `/dev/null`

Ref: https://web.archive.org/web/20190803041507/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2011/12/c_c_tip_how_list_compiler_predefined_macros

note: for swig user, on Linux x86_64 use `-DSWIGWORDSIZE64`

## MacOS

On Catalina 10.15 IIRC

### Clang

```bash
clang -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | grep INT64_TYPE
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long long int
#define __UINT64_TYPE__ long long unsigned int
```

Clang:
`-dM` dumps a list of macros.
`-E` prints results to stdout instead of a file.
`-x c` and `-x c++` select the programming language when using a file without a filename extension, such as `/dev/null`

Ref: https://web.archive.org/web/20190803041507/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2011/12/c_c_tip_how_list_compiler_predefined_macros

note: for swig user, on macOS x86_64 **don't** use `-DSWIGWORDSIZE64`

## Visual Studio 2019

First
`sizeof(long int) == 4` and `sizeof(long long) == 8`

in `stdint.h` we have:

```cpp
#if _VCRT_COMPILER_PREPROCESSOR

typedef signed char        int8_t;
typedef short              int16_t;
typedef int                int32_t;
typedef long long          int64_t;
typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short     uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
```

note: for swig user, on windows x86_64 **don't** use `-DSWIGWORDSIZE64`

## SWIG Stuff

First see  https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/3a329566f8ae6210a610012ecd60f6455229fe77/Lib/stdint.i#L20-L24 so you can control the typedef using `SWIGWORDSIZE64` but...

now the bad: [SWIG Java](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/3a329566f8ae6210a610012ecd60f6455229fe77/Lib/java/java.swg#L74-L77) and [SWIG CSHARP](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/1e36f51346d95f8b9848e682c2eb986e9cb9b4f4/Lib/csharp/csharp.swg#L117-L120) do not take it into account

So you may want to use

```
#if defined(SWIGJAVA)
#if defined(SWIGWORDSIZE64)
%define PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(NEW_TYPE, TYPE)
%clear NEW_TYPE;
%clear NEW_TYPE *;
%clear NEW_TYPE &;
%clear const NEW_TYPE &;
%apply TYPE { NEW_TYPE };
%apply TYPE * { NEW_TYPE * };
%apply TYPE & { NEW_TYPE & };
%apply const TYPE & { const NEW_TYPE & };
%enddef // PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP
PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(long int, long long);
PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(unsigned long int, long long);
#undef PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP
#endif // defined(SWIGWORDSIZE64)
#endif // defined(SWIGJAVA)
```

and

```
#if defined(SWIGCSHARP)
#if defined(SWIGWORDSIZE64)
%define PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(NEW_TYPE, TYPE)
%clear NEW_TYPE;
%clear NEW_TYPE *;
%clear NEW_TYPE &;
%clear const NEW_TYPE &;
%apply TYPE { NEW_TYPE };
%apply TYPE * { NEW_TYPE * };
%apply TYPE & { NEW_TYPE & };
%apply const TYPE & { const NEW_TYPE & };
%enddef // PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP
PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(long int, long long);
PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP(unsigned long int, unsigned long long);
#undef PRIMITIVE_TYPEMAP
#endif // defined(SWIGWORDSIZE64)
#endif // defined(SWIGCSHARP)
```

So `int64_t` aka `long int` will be bind to Java/C# `long` on Linux...

Comment: *First `long long` and `long int` are different types but `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(long int) == sizeof(int64_t)`*  Oh?  Try compiling with `-m32`....

Comment: @AndrewHenle sorry it was implicitly targeted to k8 architecture host development, otherwise you won't have any swig issue for 32bits

Answer (score 5):

An int64_t should be 64 bits wide on any platform (hence the name), whereas a long can have different lengths on different platforms. In particular, sizeof(long) is often 4, ie. 32 bits.