# Unable to build Qt 5.0 on Solaris 10

Tags: qt, build, solaris, qt5, solaris-10

I am currently working on a cross platform project in Qt. I am currently developing on Linux (Mint x64) but need to deploy parts of the project to a Solaris 10 server.

I have been trying to build Qt5.0.1 on solaris now for about 3 days with little success!

I have downloaded the sources from [here](http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1.tar.gz) and successfully extracted the archive.

When trying to run the configure script, I first ran into syntax errors which were fixed by changing the qtbase/configure script to use /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh.

I have then run into several problems when running configure:

```
./configure -platform solaris-g++
```

- Configure cannot detect architecture (not a breaking failure but...)
- "No QPA platform plugin enabled!" - I have explicitly installed (using pkgutil) libxcb and xcbutil
- When using the -no-qpa-platform-guard flag, configure completes, then:

  - I get an assortment of errors in building when I run gmake -j4

The compilation errors are:

```
In file included from ../3rdparty/pcre/pcre16_compile.c:43:0:
../3rdparty/pcre/pcre_compile.c: In function 'compile_branch':
../3rdparty/pcre/pcre_compile.c:5193:18: error: 'int64_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
../3rdparty/pcre/pcre_compile.c:5193:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../3rdparty/pcre/pcre_compile.c:5194:36: error: expected ')' before 'length_prevgroup'
../3rdparty/pcre/pcre_compile.c:5264:32: error: expected ')' before 'repeat_max'gcc -c -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_LIBUDEV -DQT_NO_EVDEV -DQT_NO_XCB -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DQT_USE_ICU -DPCRE_HAVE_CONFIG_H -DHB_EXPORT=Q_CORE_EXPORT -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -I../../mkspecs/solaris-g++ -I. -I../../include -I../../include/QtCore -I../../include/QtCore/5.0.1 -I../../include/QtCore/5.0.1/QtCore -Iglobal -I../3rdparty/pcre -I../3rdparty/md5 -I../3rdparty/md4 -I.moc/release-shared -I/usr/sfw/include -o .obj/release-shared/pcre16_dfa_exec.o ../3rdparty/pcre/pcre16_dfa_exec.c
gmake[3]: *** [.obj/release-shared/pcre16_compile.o] Error 1
gmake[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[3]: Leaving directory `/export/home/emackenzie/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1/qtbase/src/corelib'
gmake[2]: *** [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/export/home/emackenzie/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1/qtbase/src'
gmake[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/export/home/emackenzie/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1/qtbase'
gmake: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**[UPDATE]**
Ok, so I have solved this compile error by commenting out pcre_internal.h:217,218,219,221:

```
//#if HAVE_STDINT_H
//#include <stdint.h>
//#elif HAVE_INTTYPES_H
#include <inttypes.h>
//#endif
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
io/qtemporarydir.cpp: In member function 'void QTemporaryDirPrivate::create(const QString&)':
io/qtemporarydir.cpp:150:30: error: 'mkdtemp' was not declared in this scope
gmake[3]: *** [.obj/release-shared/qtemporarydir.o] Error 1
```

I have checked the source and stdlib.h is being included (where mkdtemp should be declared) and it is on the filesystem in /usr/include

Again any help would be great.

Comment: cf. my related question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20879715/427158

Answer (score 0):

Figure out which header in your system declares `int64_t` and `#include` it on **pcre_compile.c**.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a nicer solution as none of the code that I am compiling is mine, it is all the standard Qt sources. Also I believe int64_t is not defined in a single place... (there are multiple different headers that declare it)

Comment: You can define it yourself: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604137/definition-of-int64-t).