# C++: int64_t where does it come from?

Tags: c++

I was wondering where types like int64_t come from. Are they c++ standard or os-dependent? (1)

Also, do you know where I can find documentation about these types? I couldn't find useful information so far. Do they have a special name? (2)

What's their general difference with regards to the standard primitive types like int,long... (3)

Thank you and Regards

Comment: See [this related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604137/definition-of-int64-t).

Comment: Looking for [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) ?

Comment: The types are only conditionally defined if the platform is able to provide the guarantees they make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were introduced by C99 standard.

Documentation:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/ 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

They were introduced because the standard doesn't specify fixed width for standard primitives, but a minimum width. So `int` can be 16-bit or 32-bit, depending on compiler, OS, and architecture, `long` varies as well as it can be 32-bit or 64-bit. Even `char` can be 8 or 16 bits.

Answer (score 8):

It comes from a header file:

`#include <stdint.h>` // C standard library
`#include <cstdint>`  // C++ standard library

Answer (score 4):

int64_t is typedef you can find that in

```
   <cstdint>
```