# fast rounding fixed point number

Tags: c++

Let's say I treat my integer as if it has 4 fraction bits. And now 0 is zero, 16 is one, 32 is two, and it goes on. When rounding, numbers in range [-7, 7] becomes 0, [8, 23] becomes 16.

My code is this:

```
std::int64_t my_round(std::int64_t n) {
    auto q = n / 16;
    auto r = n % 16;
    if (r >= 0) {
        if (r >= 8) {
            ++q;
        }
    } else {
        if (r <= -8) {
            --q;
        }
    }
    return q * 16;
}
```

It's a lot of code for such a simple task. I wonder if there is a faster way to do it. I only need to support 64bit signed integer.

Edit:
There was a comment (I don't remember whom made that comment) suggested adding 15 and masking the lower bits. It didn't work. But with some trial and error, I come up with this.

```
std::int64_t my_round2(std::int64_t n) {
    if (n >= 0) {
        n += 8;
    }
    else {
        n += 7;
    }
  return n & (~15ll);
}
```

I have no idea. but `my_round2` seems to give the same result as `my_round` and is 20 times faster. If there is a way to remove the branch it would be much better.

Comment: You might want to check the assembly code that gets generated for this function when you compile with optimizations enabled; since you are using 8 and 16 which are powers-of-2, it's likely that the compiler is able to replace the integer-math operations with bitwise operations and that therefore the resulting executable is already quite efficient.  If so, then rewriting the function to be shorter likely won't gain you any runtime efficiency, but it would make the function harder for a human reader to understand.

Comment: `n += 8;` in `my_round2()` is subject to overflow.  Wei Hsieh, how do you want to handle overflow?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I found out `my_round` overflows too. Those two function still give the same result even when overflow happened. Luckily the overflow is not likely to happen. And int64_t won't be a good choice when working with values that large.

Comment: @WeiHsieh What should `my_round2(-15)` return?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica -16. Actually it's easier to think about if we scale the fixed point number to real number, that is by dividing 16. so -15 becomes -0.9375. that would round to -1 which is -16 in my fixed point representation.

Comment: @WeiHsieh The rounding mode employed here rounds half-way cases away from zero.  This differs from the common FP "round to nearest, ties to even".  I suspect you want speed more than   ["reduce bias"](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/11/11/round-to-even.html) practice, but the quality of your algorithm may improve with a different rounding.

Comment: @WeiHsieh "I wonder if there is a faster way to do it." risks [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).  With your `my_round2()` the next steps are processor dependent, what works well on a 64-bit machine  may perform horribly on a 16-bit embedded processor.  Perhaps tag with the processor  family of interest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
return (n + 8 + (n>>63)) & (~15ll);
```

one can shave off the branch from `my_round2()`, and ensure the original symmetry at zero. The idea is that `signed type >> (sizeof(signed type) * 8 - 1)` is -1 for negative values and 0 for positive values.

Clang is able to produce branchless code for the original `my_round2()` but that is still one instruction longer than the proposed routine here. With arm64 the savings are even greater.

Comment: Nice. An alternative is to replace `+(n>>63)` with `-(n<0)` which to me is clearer, but which may also depend more on compiler optimization to produce fast code.

Comment: "signed type >> (sizeof(signed type) * 8 - 1) is -1 for negative values" is _implementation-defined_.  That is also an example of IDB in the C spec: "An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right."  `-(n<0)` (@nielsen) is a good alternative.

Comment: Yes, in two's complement and all boiler plate + of course there are systems with 9 bit chars. -- except, that std::int64_t AFAIK is guaranteed to be two's complement. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/13604137/1716339)

Comment: `int64_t` must be two's complement and unpadded, yet code still has implementation-defined behavior.  Yes certainly common for the the IDB to behave as hoped but it not required - even if encoding is 2's complement.  The concern is that compilers of tomorrow may take advantage of the spec is ways not anticipated today.  Much code of days gone by coded to common practice fail today for like reasons.  Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
std::int64_t my_round2(std::int64_t n) {
    int sign = n >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
    n = sign > 0 ? n: -n;
    int64_t n1 = (n + 8) >>4;
    n1<<= 4;
    return n1 * sign;
}
```

This still has the overflow problem though.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Strange is an apt description of my choice. I can't recollect why I used `size_t` out of the blue. Have changed it to `int64_t`.

Comment: Aside: With `int64_t n1`, `n1<<= 4;` can result in _undefined behavior_:  With `uint64_t n1`,  code does not have UB, but various _implementation defined behavior_.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your integer representation is twos-complement (which is pretty much required by other things in the C11 standard), just add 8 and mask off the lower bits:

```
int64_t my_round2(int64_t n) {
    return (n + 8) & ~UINT64_C(15);
}
```

Comment: If n is -8, the result is 0, but it seems OP wants -1 in that case.